jenkins pipeline that has parameters of checkboxes and input text for each one selected
i want my jenkins pipeline to have parameters type checkboxes include docker_image_names
and for each docker_image selected so there would be a input text shown as Docker_image_TAG.
i tried to achieve this using the plugin Active Choices using HTML FORMATTED TYPE, but my image_tags i put in the input boxes are not been printed in the end.
i found this in another post the code is working:
properties([
                            parameters([
                                [$class: 'ChoiceParameter', 
                                    choiceType: 'PT_CHECKBOX', 
                                    description: 'Select the Dokcer images from the Dropdown List', 
                                    filterLength: 1, 
                                    filterable: false, 
                                    name: 'DOCKER_IMAGES', 
                                    script: [
                                        $class: 'GroovyScript', 
                                        fallbackScript: [
                                            classpath: [], 
                                            sandbox: false, 
                                            script: 
                                                "return['Could not get the services list']"
                                        ], 
                                        script: [
                                            classpath: [], 
                                            sandbox: false, 
                                            script: 
                                                "return['image1', 'image2', 'image3']"
                                        ]
                                    ]
                                ],
                                [$class: 'DynamicReferenceParameter', 
                                    choiceType: 'ET_FORMATTED_HTML', 
                                    description: 'choose image tag', 
                                    name: 'DOCKER_TAGS',
                                    omitValueField: 'true',
                                    referencedParameters: 'DOCKER_IMAGES', 
                                    script: 
                                        [$class: 'GroovyScript', 
                                        script: 'return["Could not get Information"]', 
                                        script: [
                                            script: '''
                                                    
                                                    if (DOCKER_IMAGES.equals("image1")){
                                                    inputBox="<input type ='text' id = 'myText' name='value' >"
                                                    return inputBox
                                                    }
                                                    
                                                    '''
                                                ]
                                        ]
                                ]
                            ])
                        ])
pipeline {
    environment {
         vari = ""
  }
  agent any
  stages {
      stage ("Example") {
        steps {
         script{

          echo "${params.DOCKER_IMAGES}"
          echo '\n'
          echo "${params.DOCKER_TAGS}"
       }
      }
    }
  }
}

but this logics adds only input box just when image1 is checked.
and successfully prints the value of the text input of the image_tag.
i want to expand it that every image_ been checked so i could give her its own image tag.
i tried different scripts in the DOCKER_TAGS parameter as:
def inputBox = "" DOCKER_IMAGES.split(",").each { image -> inputBox += "<input type='text' id='${image}_tag' name='params.${image}_tag'><br/>" } return inputBox                                                  
`
but i have null in the output of the build.
someone succeeded to achieve such behavior?
ii tried the code above.
